# How to win as plants in Vs. mode (Quick Play)?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies

The Xbox Live Arcade, Playstation Network, and DS versions of Plants vs. Zombies have a Vs. mode where each player plays either Plants or Zombies.  I'm having a lot of problems when taking the role of the Plants - after the Zombies got a few basic concepts down, the Plants seem to never be able to win.  Are there strategies that the Plants can effectively use to win this mode?

Update: In Quick Play mode, gamers cannot customize their seed selections. Plants get Sunflowers, Peashooters, Wallnuts, Potato Mines, Jalapeños, and Squash. The Zombies get Graves, Zombies, Conehead Zobmies, Football Zombies, Garbage Can Zombies, and Wave of Zombies.

Comment: What are the strategies the zombies use in VS mode?  It's hard to strategize for the Plants without knowing what you're up against exactly.

Comment: The Zombies focus on gravestones (which generate "brains" and protect the targets) first, generally filling all the available space.  While doing this, if there are any undefended Plant rows, they send a cheap Zombie or two there to see if they can get in the house.  Once the graves are all built, the Zombies send Football Zombies and Waves until a row is undefended, and then can easily finish with any cheap Zombie.  It seems that the Zombie economy very quickly overwhelms the Plant economy.

Comment: You can use a potato mine for the first zombie that spawns and the squash for football zombies.

Answer (score 8):

Please refer http://plantsvszombies.wikia.com/wiki/Versus_Mode

This is an excerpt of the Strategy section

> Strategy
>
> It's much like any other normal game,
>   except you must keep in mind that your
>   opponent can see what you are doing,
>   what plants you have, and where you
>   are about to place a plant. Cherry
>   Bombs and Jalepenos are useful as
>   always, and with the Coffee Bean
>   costing only 25 Sun now, the
>   Doom-shroom is much more useful in
>   this mode. The only problem is that
>   because of the six lane limit, using
>   one is an even bigger drawback and
>   should still be only used when
>   absolutely needed. You also have 3
>   less squares to build on, and should
>   keep that in mind. Just remember to
>   not just focus on defending yourself,
>   but to also try and kill the Target
>   Zombies, and you should be fine. Also,
>   remember that Lobbed-shot Plants
>   (Cabbage-pult, Kernel-pult,
>   Melon-pult) shoot over shields and
>   attack the Zombie directly.

Comment: I didn't initially realize that there was any way to customize my seeds because I'd only been playing Quick Play.  I can certainly see how the strategy is more complex when both the Plants and Zombies can have a custom loadout.  But my question is really about the Quick Play mode.

Comment: I can't use the plants recommended by this strategy in Quick Play mode.

Comment: I haven't played the quick play mode but in the campaign mode plants get unlocked as you progress through the missions. I'm not 100% sure but maybe you have to first unlock certain plants by playing the campaign? Just guessing.

Comment: I have completed all levels of the campaign mode, and unlocked all plants.

Comment: Could you please specify the ones that aren't available?

Comment: All the plants you buy from crazy dave you cant use in vs mode.